# Merge wordpress searchform code with custom html code

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I make this code (custom):

```
 <div id="sb-search" class="sb-search">
        <form>
          <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Search.." type="text" value="" name="search" id="search">
          <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" value="">
          <span class="sb-icon-search"></span>
        </form>
  </div>
```

retrieve search results like this one ( wordpress ) does:

```
 <form method="get" class="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>">
 <div>
 <input type="text" class="search" name="s" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='<?php _e('To search type and hit enter','typegrid'); ?>';" onfocus="if(this.value=='<?php _e('To search type and hit enter','typegrid'); ?>')this.value='';" value="<?php _e('To search type and hit enter','typegrid'); ?>" />
 </div>
```

Basically I got this custom code for an awesome search box with on-click slide etc. It has a field where people can type, but it gets no results as used on my wordpress site. I wanna make it able to get results from wordpress content w/o changing divs thus not altering its design. Please help, I'm stuck!!

Comment: I have tried to add method="get" and its class="searchform" instead of placeholder="Search.." on the first input line, without changing its type, "text". Sorry, I'm pretty new on stackoverflow :/

Comment: is your custom form is also in wordpress ?

Comment: I have added my custon form into the header.php (that's where my new seachbox is). The old search form is handled by the searchform.php which is inside my theme's folder. Basically both are live on the website, both working, but separate. I wanna get search results while using my custom search, instead of wordpress'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do it:

```
<div id="sb-search" class="sb-search">
  <form action="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>">
    <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Search.." type="text" value="" name="s" id="search">
    <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" value="">
    <span class="sb-icon-search"></span>
  </form>
</div>
```

All you have to do is add the form action, and make the name of the search input to be "s".

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form method="get" class="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>" >
          <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Search.." type="text" value="" name="s" id="search">
          <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" value="">
          <span class="sb-icon-search"></span>
        </form>
```

homeurl ?s=anything will call wordpress search function, so just make form's action GET and ACTION = your home url